# Svelte cannot import

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export, svelte

Im a svelte beginner and im trying to do simple feedback app, i have 2 files one with app and second with list of feedbacks
App.svelte

```
<script>
  import feedback from "./components/feedbacks.svelte";
</script>

<main>
  <p>{feedback}</p>
</main>

<style>
</style>
```

feedbacks.svelte

```
<script>
    export let feedback = [{text: 'Its good', rate: 7}, {text: 'alright', rate: 6}, {text: 'terrible', rate: 2}];
</script>
```

instead of an array it returns:

`class Feedbacks extends SvelteComponentDev { constructor(options) { super(options); init(this, options, instance$1, create_fragment$1, safe_not_equal, { feedback: 0 }); dispatch_dev("SvelteRegisterComponent", { component: this, tagName: "Feedbacks", options, id: create_fragment$1.name }); } get feedback() { throw new Error("<Feedbacks>: Props cannot be read directly from the component instance unless compiling with 'accessors: true' or '<svelte:options accessors/>'"); } set feedback(value) { throw new Error("<Feedbacks>: Props cannot be set directly on the component instance unless compiling with 'accessors: true' or '<svelte:options accessors/>'"); } }`

Comment: Did you go through the tutorial? https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Svelte files create components, if you just want plain data, do *not* use a Svelte file, just export from a `.js` (or `.ts` if using TypeScript).

(Exports from components create component properties.)